# PHP & js / jquery: how to run PHP code on click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How can I run PHP code on click of a link? (`<a>link here</a>`)?

I know how listen for a click in JavaScript or JQuery And then perform JavaScript or JQuery, but how would I do PHP?

Comment: With [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [`$_ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: can't be done unless you use ajax.

Comment: @CORRUPT those are js functions, right?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes is that a js function?

Comment: @CORRUPT your name is correct `$_ajax()` is corrupt

Comment: @jai how would I use ajax to solve this?

Comment: @robertzoon it's clickable to the jQuery documentation. It's not native JS functionality, you'll need to use `XMLHttpRequest` if not using a library, but since you already use jQuery you should use `$.ajax`.

Comment: @robertzoon http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP code is a server side code while JavaScript is a client side. Thus PHP code executes on the server while JS code executes in client's browser. There are no way to execute PHP code in client's browser but what you've probably needs is [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX).

AJAX requests can be called from client's browser to run some custom server side code which will return the result to browser. The way to do it from jQuery is using [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method or one of it variants - $.post() and $.get().

Answer (score -2):

In case you don't plan to use any ajax request, You may put your php code in a page and onclick on the hyperlink, you change the src of a frame to be the php page that you created.
note that the iframe has a width and height of 0 so it doesn't appear in the browser.

```
<iframe src='' id="myframe" frameborder="0" height="0" width="0"></iframe>
<a href='javascript:document.getElementById("myframe").src="hello.php"'>link here</a>
```

Comment: And also note that it is really ugly practice.

Comment: I know but just in case